# Use OpenIddict in a worker service scenario

Tags: openiddict

I'll like to use openiddict in a workerservice client. I'm based on the [Aridka client sample](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Aridka/Aridka.Client) but the token and refresh token management should be implemented in the top level application. Is there some options or a library who manage it under the hood ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`OpenIddictClientService` exposes high-level methods for acquiring new tokens (e.g `AuthenticateWithRefreshTokenAsync()`) but there's currently no native token management feature that will do that for you or attach access tokens to HTTP requests.

For that, you can take a look at third-party libraries, like https://github.com/stasnocap/openiddict-access-token-management.